# Best way to get 10,000 local files into a Production Rails App (thru carrierwave onto s3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

So I have a huge number of PDF's that I need to get into a production rails app (pdfs will be stored on s3 thru carrier wave).  There are already PDF's on prod and carrierwave puts the model id in the s3 path, so I need to sync up the model creation and the s3 upload.  I also have additional metadata about the pdf's that I need to store in the models.

Options I'm thinking of:

1. Expose a public api to the model creation (which kicks off the carrierwave upload). Write a script and use curl to post files (and metadata) to this api.
2. Sync prod db to my dev box, build models with the metadata, store the id of the model and use this to upload directly to s3.
3. Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at S3FS.  This will allow you to mount/unmount an S3 bucket to your local filesystem, making it very easy to manipulate its contents with typical OS file commands.

I would say however that trying to utilize the S3 mount for frequent read/write operations form the production environment can be very slow. I mainly have used the S3 mount to then rsync changes to locally attached storage for working with it in the application.